# Framing new window in detached garage load bearing wall - temporary wall necessary?

Tags: framing, windows

[image]
I have a "1.5" car garage with a single slope roof about 12ft high on the taller end. All of the walls are 2x4 framing with a double top plate. I would like to install a 48x48 windows in the taller, load bearing wall. It looks like I'll need to cut into 3 existing studs to frame out the window.

My plan was to install 2 new king studs, 2 new jack studs, a double 2x8 header, rough sill and trim 3 existing studs that will become the cripples both above and below the window.
[image]

I have 2 questions:

1. Does my framing look correct?
2. Would it be necessary to built a temporary wall to support the roof if this is all done in 1 day with no snow load? If so, how far from the existing wall can the temp wall be (trying to limit the amount of extra lumber I need to buy)?

Thank you in advance!

Comment: What's your design snow load? 1.5 car? Is that 18 ft wide?

Comment: @popham I'm not sure, how would I calculate that?

Comment: The design snow load in my city is on the city's website. Search the web for your city's name and `design snow load`. It'll probably be in the top 3 results.

Comment: I can't find anything for mine or neighboring towns, looks like it's a "case study area" The closest town I could find was 30.0 psf

Comment: you might have to move that tie also.

Comment: @Jasen are you referring to the 2x8 running perpendicular to the wall studs? How would I determine that? I always assumed it was there for lateral bracing.

Comment: Yes, you'll be cutting through what it attaches to so it will likely be bracing less well than it used to.

Comment: Based on your proximity to a particular Army base and a table linked from https://www.eng-tips.com/viewthread.cfm?qid=284930, I figure your snow load at 50psf. It's probably less. You would call a local building department to verify.

Comment: @popham ok cool, so what do I do with this information?

Comment: @Yev, the snow load is an input for sizing your header. See IRC Table R602.7(1) linked from my answer.

Comment: What is that 4' by 4' patch of lumber just to the right of the "rafter tie"?

Comment: @popham previous owners attempt to cover the walls in plywood and I guess he ran out.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your single king studs are good based on [IRC R602.7.5](https://codes.iccsafe.org/content/IRC2021P2/chapter-6-wall-construction#IRC2021P2_Pt03_Ch06_SecR602.7.5). Assuming a 50 psf snow load, [IRC Table R602.7](https://codes.iccsafe.org/content/IRC2021P2/chapter-6-wall-construction#IRC2021P2_Pt03_Ch06_SecR602.7) indicates that a double 2x6 header with single jack studs is adequate. If you install the double 2x8 header, [IRC Table R602.7](https://codes.iccsafe.org/content/IRC2021P2/chapter-6-wall-construction#IRC2021P2_Pt03_Ch06_SecR602.7) indicates that double jack studs are necessary to develop the header's excess strength.

From your image I see 3 cripples, implying 4 16" gaps, implying a 64" width of roof joists without support during construction. Assuming 10 psf dead load (appropriate for roof joists + OSB sheathing + 1 layer of asphalt shingles) and assuming an 18' wide span, that's a total load of (10psf)(5'-4")(9') = 480#. For #2 Spruce top plates, this is 190% of the top plate's strength, so temporary shoring is definitely warranted. For an 18' building width, keep the temporary shoring within 3'-6" of the wall (less than 1/4 of the adjacent span's length, i.e. 3.5' < (18' - 3.5')/4).

A 12 ft wall is unusually tall. I can imagine a designer using that horizontal piece above your window to brace the wall against the roof diaphragm. If that were the case, however, then there would be detailing analogous to a waler beam along the wall to distribute the brace stiffness to other wall studs. I therefore conclude that this horizontal piece's purpose is to stiffen the garage door tracks. The cripple adequately supports this bracing for the garage door track.

Comment: Do you know, would the rafter tie (is that what its called) be fine attached to a cripple?

Comment: @Yev, I've updated the answer to reflect my opinion. I believe that horizontal piece is there to stabilize your garage door tracks.

Comment: @Yev, I found a moment in time from a YouTube video that shows what I mean by a "waler beam": https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=iw2QEoc3GrA&t=3m36s. Your horizontal piece is analogous to the compression brace going across the video's excavation. If you remove the waler, i.e. that I-beam tipped on its side, then the brace would only reinforce a tiny little patch of wall.

Comment: @Yev, that's not a rafter tie. A pair of rafters installed without a ceiling exert outward forces against the walls because of the hinge at the roof's ridge. You have no ridge and therefore no hinge, so there's no outward force for rafter ties to resist.

Comment: I had also always assumed that it was for the garage door tracks, however, I don't know if you can tell from the photo - the tracks are not actually mounted to it as its too far forward.

Comment: The rough opening of the window is 48"x48" - for the cripples it would actually only be 2x 16" gaps + 2 smaller gaps totaling 48". Building size is 20' x 16'

Comment: @Yev, I assumed a worst case scenario where you cut the opening before installing king studs. That's where the 64" comes from. I stand by my rejection of that brace as structural unless there's something attached to the structure's outside at the connection point. Rafter ties can be installed periodically because roof sheathing and top plate bending transfer the stiffness to adjacent rafters. That wall's sheathing doesn't have adequate strength or stiffness to analogously strengthen or stiffen adjacent wall studs. I suppose it could be a failed attempt.

Comment: @Yev, it wouldn't be responsible to post here, but if there are no top plate splices above your window, then technically there's a fastener schedule for face nailing the top plates together that develops the stacked top plates into a 3" deep beam. That 3" deep beam has the strength and stiffness to carry the 10 psf dead load. If you intend to build without the temporary wall, then let me know so I can at least give you that nailing schedule.

Comment: @Yev, and your 12' wall with all of that sheathing above the window provides quite a bit of strength and stiffness through the cripples even without a temporary wall or 3" beam. I would do all of that work without any temporary wall.

Comment: I planned on installing my king studs and jacks studs first, then assembling my header and only then cutting into the framing to minimize the time of structural compromise. There is nothing outside of the structure. 

I would be curious in the nailing pattern you mentioned.

Also, in your last comment, you are saying you *would do* all of that work without any temporary wall?

Comment: @Yev, yeah, I wouldn't do the temporary wall. You could install a 2x6 across the inside of the king studs and the cripples, where the nails at each cripple would transfer the load to the king studs. Even that seems unnecessary because your exterior sheathing is effectively doing it already. 3-10d common nails at each king stud are good for 375# together, see https://awc.org/calculators/connection-calculator/ where your load duration factor is 1.25 (that's for 7 days of loading).

Comment: @Yev, the nail pattern to get the 3" beam is basically a 10d common nail every 1-1/4" on a staggered pattern, where the spacing could increase to every 2-1/2" in the middle 24" of the span. Sounds like a giant pain. The temporary face nailed 2x6 better appeals to my laziness.

Comment: I actually thought about doing exactly that. Thanks so much for the detailed input and explanations.

Comment: @Yev, sure. Sorry for the uncertainty over that mysterious horizontal piece.